# Edit long string comfortable in excel

Tags: excel, vba

**What i try to accomplish:**
I have long strings in my cells and want to edit them comfortable. After that i want to write them back into that cell.

**What i tried already:**
I tried to copy the text over to word bullitpoint separated and write the text back into the excel cells. But that is a bit like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer. I also know the input box and the msgbox but i was not able to get my problem solved with this.

**What i am looking for:**
I am looking for a click event that puts my text into a popup window where i can edit the text and write it back to the cell that release the event or another way to edit my strings comfortable.

Comment: **what is your specific programmatic question?**

Comment: I created an Add-in long time ago which does this. Let me search it for you. But before that (since you want this in an `event`, I have quick question for you. how long should the strings be before that pop up appears?

Comment: hi! i just counted the longest i have, it is maximum 1200 letters long.

Comment: No I am talking about minimum

Comment: Ah ok, the minimum is two letters.

Comment: Are you sure? This popup will apprear on your worksheet everytime you enter >= 2 characters? It can be really annoying...

Comment: ah, ok. let me explain. there is either text in the cells or there is a "no" in there. The user opens the document and can see all the cells with either 'no' or text in there. Now if he wants to edit a text he can click in the cell. As soon as he clicks the cell the pop-up opens and he can edit it. I can also delete the 'no' and left it blank. That would be no problem.

Comment: Okk gimme 2 mins... posting an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logic:**

1. Create a `Userform` instead of using `Inputbox`. So that you can edit the text. `MsgBox` is out of the question as you will not be able to edit anything.
2. In the `Worksheet_Change` launch the userform and you can then edit the text there and finally write it back to the worksheet.

**Basic Preparation:**

Open your VBA Editor and insert a userform. Add a `TextBox` and a `CommandButton`. It might look something like this.

[image]

**Code: Paste this in the userform's code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With TextBox1
        .MultiLine = True
        .WordWrap = True
        .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
        .EnterKeyBehavior = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**Code: Paste this in the relevant worksheet code area**

```
'~~> Length of characters
Const nChars As Long = 2

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sString As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Check if there was a Paste/Autofill done
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '~~> Check if the length is more than 2
    If Len(Target.Value) > nChars Then
        '~~> Set the userform's textbox text
        With UserForm1
            .TextBox1.Text = Target.Value
            .Show
            '~~> Get the value back to the sheet
            Target.Value = .TextBox1.Text
        End With
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Code In Action:**

[image]

Once the text is populated, We make the relevant changes (*I moved the 2nd sentence to a new line*) and press the `Update` Button.

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help :)